# when i take input from user and wanna convert that input,the system errors

Tags: python-2.x

[enter image description here][1]

```html
from word2number import w2n
w2n.word_to_num('one')
1


q = input('write your number letters : ')
>>>two
w2n.word_to_num('q')
>>>NameError: name 'two' is not defined
```

i use word2number package to convert word to number, like; two = 2. when i take input from user and wanna convert that input,the system errors.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / What do you expect? / What error do you get? **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the full code as text that you are trying that is giving you errors.

But the code from the Word2number documentation is working fine for me.

https://pypi.org/project/word2number/

**Python 3**

```
from word2number import w2n
print(w2n.word_to_num('point one'))
```

Output:
0.1

**Python 2**

```
from word2number import w2n
print w2n.word_to_num('point one')
```

Output:
0.1